# Can't get JS to bubble event

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-events, event-propagation

I've got a structure as in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Arne651/s8wbeyh5/11/

```
<ul id="ul">
  <li class="test">
    <p>
      Some text
    </p>
  </li>
  <li class="test">
    <p>
      Some text
    </p>
  </li>
  <li class="test">
    <p>
      Some text
    </p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I've got an event on a `<ul>` element, in which im trying to do something with the `<li>` element that was clicked. This `<li>` element contains a `<p>` element and the event doesn't seem to bubble upwards.

```
let ul = $("#ul")
ul.on("click", function(e) {
    let clicked = $(e.target)
    console.log(clicked)
    if (clicked.hasClass("test")) {
        console.log("li triggered")
    }
})
```

I don't want events on all the `<li>` elements because the list can get quite long and a single event feels neater.

Comment: Is jQuery working?

Comment: I'm using it in a part I didn't include here to add all the li's to the ul so yeah, jQuery is working.

Comment: There is one doubt, as the e.target will be the ul, so you are checking whether a class is there in that ul, it won't be there. if you are clicking on the ul, from the ul you need to find closest li and check hasClass then it will return true

Comment: `console.log(e.target)` returns a `<p>` tag @DILEEPTHOMAS

Comment: Yep, so as in your question mentioned you were checking on the p tag where class it's not there as christian suggested the answer  cool Happy coding :)
Sorry on the confusion it was mentioned as instead of ul it will be p tag 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When clicking the text, the target is the p tag.

Getting the closest li might not be the best way to do this but this works.

```
ul.on("click", function(e) {
    let clicked = $(e.target).closest('li');
    console.log(clicked);
    if (clicked.hasClass("test")) {
        console.log("li triggered");
    }
});
```

Comment: This feels disgusting, but does work so I'm marking this as correct answer.

Comment: I agree, you could do the following but its less dynamic for the future 
```let target = $(e.target);
    let clicked = target.is("li") ? target : target.parent();```
This will check if you have clicked the li or a sibling and selects the parent if its a sibling.
But realistically my first answer is future proof, but not as efficient. i.e. if you were to add another layer of elements to the li tag this would break.

Answer (score 0):

you can add the click on the li only try this

```js
let li = $("#ul li.test")
li.on("click", function(e) {
  console.log("li triggered");
})
```

I am first fetching all li that have calse test then add the listener on them.

Comment: I would like to work with a single event on the ul. My course's theory specifies this as the better way to do things :/